# How to host asp.net webform dynamic website on plesk server?

Tags: asp.net

I am uploded database of the website and also publish project through visual studio but run successfully what i do? If any setting required for this please tell me...?

Comment: i don't think plesk supports asp.net?

Comment: no plesk supports asp.net i am searching on it....

Comment: then it must be only asp.net core they support. make sure you have a version of it that is correct